# DNS Protection in named.conf

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, web-server, bind

cat /etc/named.conf

```
[...]
acl "trusted" {
IPS HERE
};

options {
allow-recursion { trusted; };
allow-notify { trusted; };
allow-transfer { trusted; };
allow-query { trusted; };
directory "/var/named";
dump-file "/var/named/named_cache_dump.db";
statistics-file "/var/named/named_stats.log";
empty-zones-enable no;
};
[...]
```

I saw the following and was wondering what IPs do I need to whitelist? Am I adding the root-nameservers?

I want to know how to protect myself from DNS attacks like illegal transfers/recursion/poisoning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really need two ACLs to handle that properly.  One for peer name servers, and one for clients.

```
acl "nameservers" {
    # A list of all the name servers that this server has transfers or receices zones from
    # should basically be all the masters/slave name servers, for all defines zones
};

acl "internalclients" {
    # all your internal networks/client machines that can use this name server for resolution.
    127.0.0.0/8;
    10.0.0.0/8;
    172.16.0.0/12;
    192.168.0.0/16;
};

options {
    allow-notify { nameservers; };
    allow-transfer { nameservers; };
    allow-recursion { internalclients; };
    allow-query { internalclients; };
};

zone "example.org" {
    allow-query {any;};
    allow-transfer { nameservers; };
};
```

For the best level of poisoning protection you really shouldn't be serving zones from the same DNS servers that you are using for client resolution though.  But if you trust your internal clients, then I believe a setup like this is adequate.

Comment: So ACL nameservers is the IPs of my nameservers? -- if dns is hosted on same server as clients, it possible they could hijack transfers?

Comment: Yes, the nameservers acl is a list of all your name servers.  I don't think they your clients could hijack a transfer, but I am not 100% certain.